# How include MapDB in a GWT project

Tags: java, gwt, mapdb

I'm using this [Guide](http://www.mapdb.org/doc/quick-start/#get-it) for adding MapDb to my project.
i'm trying to make a simple user registration but i don't understand where and how i can put the lib inside my project!

Where include this code

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapdb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapdb</artifactId>
    <version>VERSION</version>
</dependency>
```

and this code

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapdb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapdb</artifactId>
        <version>VERSION</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

i'm new with GWT and MapDB and if someone can tell me how put the libraries of MapDB with all steps it's can be very grateful!

After that i manage the data store/retrieve in the server gwt application?

Answer (score 0):

While this is a very old question, I'll reply in case it's still helpful to you.

The XML configuration code you've quoted above should be inserted in a [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) POM file.  Maven is a configuration management tool for Java-based projects.

If you aren't using or don't want to start using Maven, you can download the jar from Maven central and add it manually to your project.